# Как правильно вывести сумму?

Tags: javascript

в спан попадает 9

а не 4

```js
let button = document.querySelector('button');
let elems = document.querySelectorAll('input');
let span = document.querySelector('span');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  elems.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(Number(item.value));
    span.innerHTML = Number(item.value) * Number(item.value);
  })

})
```

```html
<input type="text" value="1">
<input type="text" value="3">
<button>click</button>
<span>0</span>
```

Comment: Вы умножаете 3 на 3, поэтому так получается  Number(item.value) * Number(item.value);

Answer (score 2):

```
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const sum = elem.reduce(function(result, item) {
    return (result + item.value);
  }, 0);
  span.innerHTML(sum);
});
```

Comment: В коде, наверное, `elems`, а не `elem`? Но всё равно код не работает. Ошибка `Uncaught TypeError: elems.reduce is not a function`. Я так понимаю, это потому что `elems`, полученные через querySelectorAll не совсем массив и у него нет метода `reduce`.

Answer (score 1):

```
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let sum = 0;
  elems.forEach(function(item) {
    sum += Number(item.value);
    console.log(sum);
  })
  span.innerText = sum;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let button = document.querySelector('button');
let elems = document.querySelectorAll('input');
let span = document.querySelector('span');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    sum += Number(elems[i].value);
  }
  span.innerHTML = sum;
})
```

```html
<input type="text" value="1">
<input type="text" value="3">
<button>click</button>
<span>0</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let button = document.querySelector('button');
let elems = document.querySelectorAll('input');
let span = document.querySelector('span');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  span.textContent = Array.from(elems).reduce((sum, elem) => {
    return sum + +elem.value;
  }, 0);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" value="1">
<input type="text" value="3">
<button>click</button>
<span>0</span>
```